# Unable to configure Windows 7 Local Area Connection with switch

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, home-networking

**DSL Router**: Pirelli DRG A125G

**Switch**: SpeedTouch 585 DSL Router

- connected (cable) with two computers, one XP, one Windows 7
- DHCP Disabled.

The XP computer connects without problem, acquiring automatically the Default Gateway of the DSL Router. But the Windows 7 computer is not able to connect: Status "Unidentified Network", Connectivity "No network access". Default Gateway "Blank", IPv4 on different subnet: 169.254.164.18 instead of expected 192.168.1.x

The Windows 7 pc connects fine on Wireless Connection, but the problem is the Local Area Connection, which is what I want to use.

http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/8/22715250179-orig.png

So what should I do from here, shouldn't Windows 7 be able to acquire correct settings automatically, when XP does?

---

EDIT:

I see now the problem is not with Windows 7; It's also on XP if switching LAN ports, so rather; Only one pc-LAN port on the switch acquires working IP/gateway. Testing with only a single computer, DSL router connected to Switch LAN-1, then pc must be connected to LAN-2 for it to work, else it fails with "unidentified network / no network access". So may I assume this is incorrect setup of the switch?

---

EDIT 2:

Just discovered that SpeedTouch Port 3 and 4 are defined as "video".  I guess this means it can not work as a switch...(?) 
http://img1.uploadscreenshot.com/images/orig/8/22719475753-orig.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that SpeedTouch Port 3 and 4 are defined as "video". I guess this means it can not work as a switch.

Answer (score 0):

**I would suggest updating the network driver.**

Steps to update network driver:

1. Click on start button.
2. In the search box type devmgmt.msc and then press enter.
3. Select the network card device and right click on it
4. Now select properties.
5. In the properties window, under Driver tab, click on Update Driver button.
6. After the installing the updates restart the computer.

**If that doesn't work, I would try resetting the TCP/IP stack.**

To reset the TCP/IP stack go to this article and either click on "Fix it for me" or follow the instructions to fix it yourself: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357 .

My last suggestion would be to disable any third-party firewall or internet protection suite because sometimes those could be causing you problems, especially McAfee.

Comment: Thanks! Tried these 3 suggestions, but it made no change to default gateway or IPv4.

Comment: Seems current setup only accept connection on one LAN port, as of EDIT above..